# MySQL query runs successfully on local but gives DATE_FORMAT error on SERVER

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've this MySQL / MariaDB query:

```
SELECT
   a.id as agent_id
 , a.full_name
 , a.email
 , a.phone
 , a.location
 , COUNT(cs.agent_id) AS tot_subscribers
 , (SELECT
      IFNULL(SUM(COUNT(cs.id)), 0) 
    WHERE
      DATE_FORMAT(cs.transaction_id, '%c') = 3
   ) AS month_subscribers
 FROM
   agents a
 LEFT JOIN
   cream_sales cs
 ON
   a.id = cs.agent_id
 GROUP BY
   a.id
```

It runs successfully on my localhost but it gives the following DATE_FORMAT error when running on the server:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE DATE_FORMAT(cs.transaction_id, '%c') = 3) AS month_subscribers FROM agents' at line 1
```

Local DBMS details:

```
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
Protocol version: 10
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b5c5906d452ec590732a93b051f3827e02749b83 $
```

Server DBMS Details:

```
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.2.13-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
Protocol version: 10 
cpsrvd 11.68.0.33
Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
```

Can anyone please help me find whats causing the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've formatted and indented your SQL code, SQL code on one line is pretty much unreadable.

Comment: Thanks, @Raymond.

Comment: You might fix MariaDB's parsing error when you add `FROM DUAL` to the co-related subquery `SELECT
      IFNULL(SUM(COUNT(cs.id)), 0)  FROM DUAL
    WHERE
      DATE_FORMAT(cs.transaction_id, '%c') = 3
   ) AS month_subscribers`

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks so much, using "FROM DUAL" worked its magic. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ... )/MONTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) instead of relying on formatted data:

```
SELECT a.id as agent_id,
      a.full_name,
      a.email, a.phone, a.location, COUNT(cs.agent_id) AS tot_subscribers,
     (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(COUNT(cs.id)), 0)
      WHERE  MONTH(cs.transaction_id) = 3) AS month_subscribers 
FROM agents a 
LEFT JOIN cream_sales cs 
  ON a.id = cs.agent_id 
 GROUP BY a.id;
```

**EDIT:**

There is no need for subquery. Conditional aggregation will do the same:

```
SELECT a.id as agent_id,
      a.full_name,
      a.email, a.phone, a.location, COUNT(cs.agent_id) AS tot_subscribers,
      SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(cs.transaction_id) = 3 
                     THEN cs.id END)) AS month_subscribers 
FROM agents a 
LEFT JOIN cream_sales cs 
  ON a.id = cs.agent_id 
 GROUP BY a.id, a.full_name, a.email, a.phone, a.location;
```

Comment: i doubt that this will help.. MariaDB has a parsing SQL error

Comment: Yep it runs successfully on my local but still gives me the same type of following error on my server: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE  MONTH(cs.transaction_id) = 3) AS month_subscribers
FROM agents a
LEFT' at line 5

Comment: @razn Please check version with CASE

Comment: @lad2025 Can you please describe me a bit in detail what do you mean?

Comment: @lad2025 Your query gives "Invalid use of Group By" error. But Thanks so much  for your effort. @ Raymond Nijland suggestion to use FROM DUAL solved the issue.

Comment: @razn I would solve invalid group by `GROUP BY a.id, a.full_name, a.email, a.phone, a.location;` There is no need for correlated subquery

Answer (score 1):

`SUM(COUNT(...))` does not make sense.  Don't nest aggregate functions.

Perhaps this is what you need for that one column:

```
( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM cs
      WHERE MONTH(transaction_id) = 3
) AS month_subscribers
```

Notes:

- `COUNT(x)` checks `x` for being not null.
- `MONTH()` is simpler (but not any more efficient).